# split in java causing "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "

Tags: java, string, split, numberformatexception

Here I have written a piece of code

```
try {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("vectorValues.txt"));
        HashMap tokenVector = new HashMap();
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Enter word : ");
            word = scan.next(); //giving input normal word
            System.out.println("Enter Vector values <happy,sad,angry,surprise> :");             
            vec = scan.nextLine(); //giving input as vector : "8 5 6 7"
            firstLine = vec.split(" ");
            //Here I am trying to print
            for(String s:firstLine)
                System.out.println("Splitted part : "+s);
            hap = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[0]); 
            sad = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[1]);
            ang = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[2]);
            sur = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[3]); 

            tokenVector.put(word, new Vector(hap,sad,ang,sur));

            System.out.println("Enter more : (0 for no) : ");
            if(scan.nextInt()==0)
                break;
        }
        os.writeObject(tokenVector);
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Vector class is here

```
class Vector implements Serializable{
    int happy,sad,angry,surprise;
    public Vector(int hap,int sad,int ang,int sur){
        happy = hap;
        this.sad = sad;
        angry = ang;
        surprise = sur;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return ""+happy+" "+sad+" "+angry+" "+surprise+"\n";
    }
}
```

This is producing following error

```
Enter word : 
4 5 6 7
Enter Vector values <happy,sad,angry,surprise> :
Splitted part : 
Splitted part : 5
Splitted part : 6
Splitted part : 7
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at FileHandler.inputIntoFile(FileHandler.java:35)
    at FileHandler.main(FileHandler.java:13)
```

The word is getting accepted using next() but it is not waiting for nextLine() to input into variable vec(). Has it taken '\n' character from the previous standard input while next() and directly moved to next line , thereby storing only blank string into vec which is leading a NumberFormatException ?

Comment: Did you mean to use, `nextLine()` instead of `next()` when consuming your `word` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you aren't eating up the \n character in your first statement:

```
 System.out.println("Enter word : ");
            word = scan.next(); //try nextLine() here
            System.out.println("Enter Vector values <happy,sad,angry,surprise> :");             
            vec = scan.nextLine(); //giving input as "8 5 6 7"
            firstLine = vec.split(" ");
```

Try `nextLine()` for your first input.

```
word = scan.nextLine();
```

Or put `nextLine()` after like:

```
word = scan.next();
scan.nextLine();
```

After your `nextInt()` put this:

```
if(scan.nextInt()==0)
                break;
scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: @Akash that's because you need to eat up the new line after your `nextInt()`

Comment: @Akash I just updated my answer check it out you should also consume the new line after your `nextInt()` call.